# Previously deleted constraints show up as conflict in Xcode 9.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, xcode9.4

I have an issue where previously deleted constraints seem to show up as conflicted. I am working in a custom xib file, messed around with constraints a bit and decided to start over by using `Clear constraints` for `All Views in Container`. I then added new constraints and now I get the following list of conflicts:

[image: Conflicted constraints]

I am positive these constraints do not exist anymore.

I can't select further down than the selected one, can't right click or double click. Same goes for the context menu, the checkboxes are unselectable:

[image: Conflicted constraints context menu]

I have tried `Product` > `Clean`, also restarted Xcode. No luck. The project builds fine and my constraints are applied correctly, I just would like to get rid of the warnings.

Comment: It may be easier to just delete the object/view and redo all the constraints for it. It's always nice to start something fresh, otherwise you are a lot more prone to problems. It's like having a shirt with loads of holes in, you can't just keep patching it up, you just get a new shirt otherwise you will have many more problems down the road.

Comment: Isn't that what "Clear constraints" is for? Recreating everything is a lot of work...

Comment: I cannot tell if this is a bug or not, but it will probably be quicker to redo it. It should take just a few minutes at most.

Comment: Except it doesn't. This really isn't the preferred way.

Comment: Try looking in the *Document Outline* view for the constraints.

Comment: Not there either

Comment: In the project navigator, control-click on your .xib and choose Open As -> Source Code.  Are the constraints in there?

Comment: Nope they are not!

Answer (score 0):

And just like that, they are gone. Must have been some Xcode cache.